# EDGE crashes with webDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I’m using,

◦Selenium 3.12.0

◦Java binding

◦Windows 10 (build 15063.1029)

◦EDGE driver (Version: 4.15063 | Edge version supported: 15.15063 )

Here is my code to open the browser

```
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver; 
System.setProperty(“webdriver.edge.driver", C://mE//Selenium//Installation//Drivers//Edge//v15063//MicrosoftWebDriver.exe”); 
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
```

The browser (EDGE) opens for a sec and then crashes immediately. Here is the error (unknown),

```
Exception in thread “main” org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: Unknown error Build info: version: '3.11.0’, revision: 'e59cfb3’, time: ‘2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z’ os.name: 'Windows 10’, os.version: '10.0’, java.version: ‘10.0.1’ Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver at 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:111) at 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73) at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136) at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83) at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545) at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:209) at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:132) at
org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.(EdgeDriver.java:141) at
org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.(EdgeDriver.java:96) at
projectOne.classOne.main(classOne.java:66)
```

This only happens with EDGE. Other browsers (IE, Chrome & FireFox) are launching just fine. I realize that, there is a limitation that EDGE allows only one instance to be running for webDriver testing. In my case, there was no other instance of EDGE running and yet it was crashing soon after it launched. I'm wondering is there any settings changes need to be made in EDGE in order for it to work with webDriver.

Comment: Please take a minute to properly format your question as code where code is, etc. Also add a tag for the language you are using.... Java?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any other settings you need to make this work.

Sometimes this can not work if MicrosoftWebDriver.exe is stuck in a zombie-type state. So check your task manager that this isn't the case.

Your MicrosoftWebDriver.exe seems to match your windows version, but it might be worth just going to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ to just download a fresh copy to ensure there's nothing funky going on there.

Something else to try, try launching edge via this code:

```
var edgeService = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
edgeService.UseVerboseLogging = true;
var edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeService, edgeOptions);
```

You might be able to get more logging out of this too.

Answer (score 0):

Could be below reason

1. Download the Webdriver as per the OS Build Version
2. Check the Edge browser opening only one tab on manually opening the browser
   it should have only one URL in the Browser settings --> open Microsoft edge with

Answer (score 0):

Edge by dafault runs on instance to make the page load faster. This is the default setting in Windows 10. So even if we close edge one instance is always running. We can disable it. 
Follow the steps here:
https://www.askvg.com/windows-10-what-are-microsoft-edge-exe-processes-running-in-task-manager-and-how-to-disable-them/

Answer (score 0):

For me the following fix worked:

1. Go to [WebDriver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads).
2. Install Microsoft Edge Driver according to the version of edge browser(You can go to this page to have reference: [Use WebDriver (Chromium) for test automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=c-sharp)).
3. Go to downloads and unzip the driver.
4. Now you can write the following code in selenium in java.

   `System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Users\\User-name\\Downloads\\msedgedriver.exe");`

   `driver = new EdgeDriver();`

Answer (score 0):

Please heck your browser version and then pick the right one from the below link ,

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads

This is working fine for me and i too faced the similar problem.